# SQL Joining the correct username

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have the following tables

```
User
__________
id
username
email

FriendGame
__________
id
useroneid
usertwoid
status
```

I want to get games that the current user is part of, so I do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM FriendGame
WHERE useroneid=1663702020516206
OR usertwoid=1663702020516206
AND STATUS =1;
```

This is fine. Now I want to join the username, but only for the user that ISNT the supplied user (1663702020516206) since in FriendGame the given user exists EITHER as useroneid or usertwoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much translate your logic directly into an `on` clause:

```
SELECT fg.*
FROM FriendGame fg JOIN
     User u
     ON (fg.useroneid = 1663702020516206 and fg.usertwoid = u.id) or
        (fg.usertwoid = 1663702020516206 and fg.useroneid = u.id) 
WHERE 1663702020516206 in (fg.useroneid, fg.usertwoid) AND
      STATUS = 1;
```

Actually, the `where` clause is not necessary to get the right result set, but I think it makes the intention of the query clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I posted an edit but I think I misunderstood what @brux meant when they said "only the user that ISNT the supplied user" - please reject my edit